# PostgreSql doesn't use index on Join

Tags: postgresql, join

Let's say we have the following 2 tables:

```
purchases
-> id
-> classic_id(indexed TEXT)
-> other columns

purchase_items_2(a temporary table)
-> id
-> order_id(indexed TEXT)
-> other columns
```

I want to do a SQL join between the 2 tables like so:

```
Select pi.id, pi.order_id, p.id
from purchase_items_2 pi
INNER JOIN purchases p ON pi.order_id = p.classic.id
```

This thing should use the indexes no? It is not.

Any clue why?

This is the explanation of the query

```
INNER JOIN purchases ON #{@table_name}.order_id = purchases.classic_id")
```

```
                                   QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hash Join  (cost=433.80..744.69 rows=5848 width=216)
   Hash Cond: ((purchase_items_2.order_id)::text = (purchases.classic_id)::text)
   ->  Seq Scan on purchase_items_2  (cost=0.00..230.48 rows=5848 width=208)
   ->  Hash (cost=282.80..282.80 rows=12080 width=16)
         ->  Seq Scan on purchases  (cost=0.00..282.80 rows=12080 width=16)
(5 rows)
```

When I do a where query

```
Select pi.id
from purchase_items_2 pi
where pi.order_id = 'gigel'
```

It uses the index

```
                                            QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bitmap Heap Scan on purchase_items_2  (cost=4.51..80.78 rows=29 width=208)
   Recheck Cond: ((order_id)::text = 'gigel'::text)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_purchase_items_2_on_order_id  (cost=0.00..4.50 rows=29 width=0)
       Index Cond: ((order_id)::text = 'gigel'::text)\n(4 rows)
```

Comment: Perhaps the optimizer expects more or less all the records from products to be matched.  What version are you using?

Comment: The version is 12

Comment: Here is some information on the query planner: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/planner-optimizer.html .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you have no `WHERE` condition, the query has to read all rows of both tables anyway. And since the hash table built by the hash join fits in [`work_mem`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-WORK-MEM), a hash join (that has to perform a sequential scan on both tables) is the most efficient join strategy.

PostgreSQL doesn't use the indexes because it is faster without them in this specific query.

Comment: I understand, thought of that but wasn't finding anything to confirm it to me. Awesome! Thx!